# How to convert the mongoshell command into java code

Tags: java, mongodb

```
db.users.aggregate([{ $project: { total: { $subtract: [ "$dateAdded", "$sourceDate" ]}}}])
```

How can I convert the above mongo shell command to java code ? Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

Comment: Which Java driver are you using?

Comment: Use the java mongo driver - https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/ .To learn how to use it :https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/java/client/

Comment: 3.2.2 mongojava driver

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after doing so much research,able to solve my issue ...

## Solution:

```
  Document docName = new Document().append("role_id", 1);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("$dateAdded");
        list.add("$sourceDate");

        List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.<Document> asList(
                new Document("$project", new Document("total", new Document("$subtract", list))));

        AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = collection.aggregate(pipeline);

        for (Document document : iterable) {
            Long copyCount =  (Long) document.get("total");
            System.out.println("copycount" + copyCount);
        }
```